# Prevent typo3 from wrapping empty lines

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

That Typo3 packs all paragraphs into p-tags is great. However, it does so with blank lines, so in the output code snippets like `<p>&nbsp</p>` disfigure the text.

Using

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines>
```

in the typo Setup prevents these wrapping of paragraphs, even the empty ones.

But what can I do if empty lines are not to be wrapped, but those with content should already be wrapped?

Thank you in advance!